# How to disable wordpress sending outgoing emails only for certain mail address

Tags: php, wordpress

my wordpress site is sending outgoing email from cf7 and other kind of forms from wp_mail() function, is there a way to disable sending only for a list of e-mail address? (i don't want some email are used to receive free evaluation cost from my website)
Thanks in advance